# get_post_meta not working when variable used for post ID

Tags: post-meta

I think I've read every suggested article on this topic and there are some similar but nothing seems to solve my problem.  It seems like it should be simple.

I just want to be able to use `get_post_meta($id)` where `$id` was set earlier in the script or even passed into the function.  Whenever I do this I get only meta about the `_edit_lock` and `_last_edit`.

If I hardcode the post id in as say 2985 it works fine, but obviously that does not do what I need as the post will change.  For those that want to know I am triggering on the publish of a post of one custom post type to take the shortcode from that type and insert it into a different custom post type.

I am hoping that one of you brilliant people out there can help a relative newbie out here.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'dif_create_zoom_mtg_lesson', 10, 3);

function dif_create_zoom_mtg_lesson ($new_status, $old_status, $postobj) {
if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $postobj->post_type === 'zoom-meetings') {
    global $zoom;
    global $post;

    ob_start();
        echo "POST IN ENTIRETY -metas"."<br/>";
        var_dump($postobj);
        $getpostid = $postobj->ID;
        echo "postid ==>";
        var_dump($getpostid);
        echo "<br/>";
        $postmetas = get_post_meta($getpostid);
        echo "VARDUMP postmetas===>";
        var_dump($postmetas);
        echo "<br/>";
    $dif_zoom_mtg_body .= ob_get_clean();

    $dif_countdown_timer = '<p id="dif-timer"></p>';
    $dif_zoom_mtg_body .= $dif_countdown_timer;

// not working now since I cannot get meeting_id dynamically
    //$dif_zoom_mtg_body .= '[zoom_api_link meeting_id="'.$dif_zoom_mtg_id.'" link_only="no"]';

    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_type'] = 'post';
    $my_post['post_title']    = "Zoom post ID=".$getpostid;
    $my_post['post_content']  = $dif_zoom_mtg_body;
    $my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_author']   = 1;
    $my_post['post_category'] = array(0);
    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
}
```

This gives me the output of:

> POST IN ENTIRETY -metas
> object(WP_Post)#4361 (24) {
>     ["ID"]=>
>     int(2733)
>     ["post_author"]=>
>     string(1) "1"
>     ["post_date"]=>
>     string(19) "2020-06-11 16:44:55"
>     ["post_date_gmt"]=>
>     string(19) "2020-06-11 16:44:55"
>     ["post_content"]=>
>     string(61) "
>
> Xcar body
>
> ["post_title"]=>
>   string(5) "X car"
>   ["post_excerpt"]=>
>   string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=>
>   string(7) "publish"
>   ["comment_status"]=>
>   string(6) "closed"
>   ["ping_status"]=>
>   string(6) "closed"
>   ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) ""
>   ["post_name"]=>
>   string(5) "x-car"
>   ["to_ping"]=>
>   string(0) ""
>   ["pinged"]=>
>   string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=>
>   string(19) "2020-06-11 16:44:55"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
>   string(19) "2020-06-11 16:44:55"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=>
>   string(0) ""
>   ["post_parent"]=>
>   int(0)
>   ["guid"]=>
>   string(56) "https://xxxxxxx.net/?post_type=zoom-meetings&p=2733"
>   ["menu_order"]=>
>   int(0)
>   ["post_type"]=>
>   string(13) "zoom-meetings"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=>
>   string(0) ""
>   ["comment_count"]=>
>   string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=>
>   string(3) "raw"
>   }
>   postid ==>int(2733)
>   
>   VARDUMP postmetas===>array(1) {
>   ["_edit_lock"]=>
>   array(1) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(12) "1591893865:1"
>   }
>   }

Answer (score 1):

If you're hooking into `publish_post`, that fires before meta is ready.

Either get the meta from the POST object, or use a different hook - possibly [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_meta_type_meta/).